# How to calculate the f1_score in case of multilabel classification problem

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So I am doing a document classification and the class of the documents can be from `[1,2,3,...,10]`.

Now I feed the model **one** document, I get the output `[1,4,7]` but the ground truth is `[1,5]`. Now I want to calculate the f1 score using sklearn?

I can't find this format of f1 score calculation in sklearn documentation. How to do it then?

Comment: Do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004172/precision-recall-for-multiclass-multilabel-classification or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732881/how-to-calculate-f1-score-for-multilabel-classification help?

Comment: @mercator Yes it helps. Maybe I should delete it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Precision/recall for multiclass-multilabel classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004172/precision-recall-for-multiclass-multilabel-classification)

Comment: @PV8.: This one is nice. Thanks